# Why does Google Photos "Free up space" feature tell me I can free up only 12MB?

Tags: google-photos

I'm using Google Photos to backup and sync my photos to the cloud. In the menu in the Android app there's an option called "Free up storage", which will supposedly

> Remove original photos & videos from your device that are already backed up.

Clicking it brings up a dialog that says

> **Free up 12.46 MB**
>
> *Remove 6 items from device*
>
> These items have been safely backed up to your Google account. You'll still be able to view them at any time.

This makes no sense at all, considering I have backed up 500+ photos using the app. They all appear at https://photos.google.com so I'm 100% sure they are backed up. Of those 500+ photos, only 31 are recent ones (less than 30 days old) and the rest are older, up to a year old.

Why does it say that it can only remove 6 photos and free up 12 MB? Is it because my phone has 3 GB free internal storage and 20 GB free SD Card storage already?

I am aware of the "Delete from device" option to delete individual photos, what I'm interested in here is how the "Free up storage" feature works, and why it won't actually free up all the backed up photos.

Comment: @beeshyams No, it still makes no sense. I have 31 new photos (less than 30 days old) and around 500 older. So shouldn't it free upp those 500 photos that are more than 30 days old?

Comment: @beeshyams I don't understand how that would explain why I can only free up 6 photos even though I have backed upp 500+ photos? The "Device folders" only lets me choose additional folders to backup, in addition to the normal camera folder. No extra folders are selected. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: My assumption - those 6 photos were from other folders (non - camera) but that's not valid, as you didn't select them. No idea as to why this behavior